# JSON Exception : org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["Name"] not found

Tags: java, json, rest, jsonexception

I am trying to extract "Automation Admin" from the below JSON output I am getting but it gives me JSONObject["Name"] not found exception.

[image: JSON Result]

Below is the code snippet.
[image: Code snippet]

I tried replacing  ownerName = json.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(i).getString("Name"); with  ownerName = json.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(i).getString("Owner"); but even that fails.
I am able to print values of OwnerId, FirstName etc but not Name. How can I extract 'Automation Admin'?

Comment: It's not a field of the root record object, but the Owner item - so `json.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Owner").getString("Name")` or something similar

Comment: That worked. You saved my day. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use ownerName = json.getJSONArray("records").getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Owner").getString("Name")